# Fibonacci sequence calculations?

Tags: php, html, numbers, sum, fibonacci

How would I create a mechanism to pass in a positive integer and display the operand, the Fibonacci series number of the operand and the sum of all the values of the Fibonacci series up to and including the specified value?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        <title>Fib Activity 3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pick Category Using GET</h1>
        <a href="ISDWK4.php?cat=Films">Films</a>
        <a href="ISDWK4.php?cat=Music">Music</a>
        <a href="ISDWK4.php?cat=Books">Books</a>
        <br />

        <h2>Fibonacci</h2>
        <form method="get" action="fib3.php">
            <fieldset>

<label for="powerof">Fibonacci: </label>
<input type="text" name="powerof" value="<?php echo $_GET['powerof']; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name='Go' value="Calculate" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
$message = 'The fibonacci sequence is: <br />1<br />2<br />';
$powerof = 0;
$max = 10;
$temp = $max;

if (isset($_GET['powerof'])) {
    $powerof = $_GET['powerof'];
}

if ($powerof > 100) {
    $powerof = 100;
    $message = 'Sorry, your input was too high. I converted it to the maximum value of 100.<br />The fibonacci sequence is: <br />1<br />2<br />';

}

$x = 0;
$y = 1;
$z = 0;
$counter = 0;


while ($counter < $powerof) {
    if ($counter <= 1) {
        $z = 1;
    } else {
        $z = $x + $y;
    }
    echo ($z. "<br />"); 
    $x = $y;
    $y = $z;
    $counter++;
}

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

all help is appreciated

Comment: its a different stage of that yes, as i'm working on 5 activities and slowly elevating my work to the next one

Answer (score 0):

First off, you aren't quite getting the Fibonacci series correct. The first number in the Fibonacci series is 0. The script I wrote here assumes that $powerof needs to be at least 1 (this can be easily changed if you need).

I also wrote this using a recursive function which takes the number you are going to. the first number, and the second number. It will loop through by calling itself and each time, it will print out the fibonacci series at the number.

```
<?php

$powerof = 0;

if (isset($_GET['powerof'])) {
    $powerof = $_GET['powerof'];
}

$message = 'The fibonacci sequence is:';

if ($powerof > 100) {
    $powerof = 100;
    $message = 'Sorry, your input was too high. I converted it to the maximum value of 100.<br />The fibonacci sequence is:';
}

echo $message;

$first = 0;
$second = 1;

if ($powerof > 1) {
    echo '<br>0<br>1';
} else if ($powerof < 1) {
    echo ' Invalid input';
} else {
    fib($powerof, $first, $second);
}

function fib($powerof, $first, $second) {
    if( $powerof > 0 ) {
         $sum = $first + $second;
         $first = $second;
         $second = $sum;
         echo $sum.'<br>';
         fib($n-1, $first, $second);
    }
}

?>
```

I hope this all makes sense, if you have any more questions, let me know

Comment: this is helpful thanks but do you know how i can complete the second part where it displays the operand the Fibonacci series number of the operand and the sum of all the values of the Fibonacci series up to and including the specified value?

Comment: You can add a counter, and a total variable outside of the function. Increment the counter each time the function is called, and add $sum to the total each time the function is called.

Comment: If you don't mind could you edit my work and add it in as I wouldn't really know where to start with that